# Selecting nested element with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:

```
<div class="leftColumn">
  <div>
     <div class="static">
     text1
     <br>
     text2
     <br>
     (222) 123 - 4567
     <br>
     <div class="summary">
```

How can I select just the text lines using beautiful soup.

I've tried a variety of things like:

```
soup.select('.leftColumn div').text
```

but so far no dice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifouSoup `select` retrives a list. You must specify the index.

```
soup.select('.leftColumn div')[0].text.split()
```

Answer (score 4):

Mauro's answer is probably more what you wanted, but this is another way to do it and how I thought about getting the inner div text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div class="leftColumn">
  <div>
     <div class="static">
     text1
     <br>
     text2
     <br>
     (222) 123 - 4567
     <br>
     <div class="summary">
     '''
bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
for div in bs.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'leftColumn'}):
    print div.findNext('div').findNext('div').text
```