# How to access nested HTMLelement in BeautifulSoup using CSS selector

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The HTML is:

```
<span class="_hylizj6">
  <span class="_1m8bb6v">
    <span>Cena</span>
  </span>
  <span>233 zł</span>
</span>
```

Using BeautifulSoup and CSS selector, how do I access "233 zł"?

I tried:

```
airbnb_soup.select('.hylizj6 span span')
```

but no go, even though

```
airbnb_soup.select('.hylizj6 span')
```

will get "Cena"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you have done (with the exception of putting an underscore in before 'hylizj6') and then asking for the second span that immediately follows that.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('barciewicz.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> soup.select('._hylizj6  > span:nth-of-type(2)')[0].text
'233 zl'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. If the HTML is *always* the same, you could use

```
airbnb_soup.find_all('span')[-1].contents
```

Answer (score 0):

As the BeautifulSoap select() method returns a list you need to access it with the Index, in this case [0]. Please see [Selecting nested element with beautiful soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146415/selecting-nested-element-with-beautiful-soup) as reference. 
Moreover you could also take into consideration the find() or find_all() methods, depending on the type of task you need to solve.